# Dictionary with Action with unknown parameters as value

Tags: c#

I have to create a Dictionary of commands with the command (a string) being the key and the function the command is mapping to as the value.
The problem I am facing is that the functions the commands are mapping to, have different amounts of parameters with different types.

How do I achieve this? Preferably, so that I can add the functions as lambda expressions.

Ex. `dictionary.Add("square", x => x * x)`.

**EDIT**: All the mapped functions return void.

Comment: How is this useful if the values have different types (`Func<double, double>`, `Func<double, double, double>` etc)? How do you know which type to cast the value to after you got the value by a key?

Comment: The commands are hardcoded, so I know which commands I need to add. It's an assignment for my exam, that requires me to map these functions to a dictionary.

Comment: @K.Vestermark If you're just going to have the caller hard code things based on their fore-knowledge o the result, there's not point in using a generic data structure.

Comment: Dont think that this will be useful and it doesnt look like right approach.

Comment: Short version: use base type `Delegate` as the value. At the call site, you'll either know at compile time the signature or not; if so, just include a compile-time cast to the right delegate type. If not, put the arguments in an array and call `DynamicInvoke()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using `Dictionary<string, ICommand>`. Here is the sample:

```
public class Command1 : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        //user your first lambda here
    }
}

public class Command2 : ICommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        //use your second lambda here
    }
}
```

Then use them this way:

```
Dictionary<string, ICommand> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, ICommand>();

dictionary.Add("Command1", new Command1());

dictionary.Add("Command2", new Command2());
```